# relationship between database tables not sharing any foreign key(s) in ERD

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, erd

Consider an example of following database tables:

> user ( id [PK], user_name, ... )
>
> comment ( id [PK], u_id [FK], ... )
>
> reportedCommentInfo ( id [PK], c_id [FK], reporting_u_id [FK], date, ... )
>
> admin ( id [PK], user_name, ... )

According to this database schema any user can post a comment and can report other user comments based on containing abusive or spamming material. Admin can view a list of all reported comments by users and can remove comments not complying to set standards.

In this scenario admin doesn't actually have access to any of the reported comments i.e. their id(s) are not present inside the admin table, yet admin can access and manage reported comments. So while creating ERD will their be a relation between reportedCommentInfo and admin table?

i.e. basically my question is, while creating ERD/data model can we create a relationship between two tables which do not have any primary key / foreign key relationship?

or two tables can only be related if they have primary key / foreign key relationship among them.

[image: ERD for above example]

p.s: any suggestions for improving anything in either database schema or ERD structure is more than welcome.

Comment: user is someone who only have access to posting a comment in the given scenario, while admin can't post a comment, he/she can only remove those comment which will be reported by users.

Comment: As in relationship, do you mean referential integrity? You could create a composite key to keep referential integrity but it looks like id is keyed isn it?

Comment: An admin should be a superuser. Thats how I would improve that relationship.

Comment: Id make the admin a user with credentials. If you don't want them to be users then I would make the reports unique by creating a composite key where userid and postid are unique.

Comment: yes @yardpenalty id(s) here are primary keys, i have updated it in my question.

I agree with your suggestion, admin should be a superUser. My bad.

Comment: @yardpenalty, according to current database schema should there be a relationship between admin and reportedCommentInfo? if no then how this relation can be handled?

Comment: Does the ERD model the subject matter or your database design?

Comment: This seems to be a *data flow* diagram written using the iconography of an *entity-relationship* diagram. What do you think it means to have a diamond "reviews" between the ReportedCommentInfo box and the Admin box?

Comment: That's what I was asking, should these two entities be connected? Admin are supposed to manage comments. but according to schema there shouldn't be a relation there.

Comment: Your schema has user, admin & comment entities and *relationship* ReportedCommentInfo (better called Report) whose participants are users and comments, requiring lines for participations/FKs. There is no "reports" relationship, no "records reported" relationship and no "reviews" relationship. You seem to be confusing *data flow* diagrams with *entity-relationship* diagrams. Your question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to do? Draw the ER diagram for your text schema? Add to your schema then diagram it? Please *edit your question* to be clear about your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any admin can view any comment, there's no need to model a relationship between them. Don't confuse data modeling with system modeling. The data model only needs to model facts that you want to record. If you want to keep track of which admins reviewed which comments, then you certainly can introduce a relationship between them. However, you don't need a relationship just to give admin users access to all comments. Rather, your application code can check whether the logged-in user is an admin user or not, and depending on their status show different buttons or content.

You ask whether "two tables can only be related if they have primary key / foreign key relationship among them". In the relational and entity-relationship perspectives, we don't relate tables, we use tables to relate sets of values. Some sets represent real-world things (like users) while others represent labels (like names) or measurements (like dates). Any two or more sets of values can be related by creating a suitable table for that purpose. Foreign key constraints are used to indicate that one column (set of values) is a subset of another column (set of values), not to associate rows. For more on this topic, I recommend a book like *Applied Mathematics for Database Professionals* by Lex de Haan and Toon Koppelaars.

Comment: so according to this concept and current db schema, admin table won't have any relationship with any other table and yet it can manage Reportedcomments.

So should I try to update my schema to show this relation as well?, or it is alright for two entities not to have any relationship in ERD yet they do have such relationships in the actual world?

I have been lately alot into design diagrams of a project, that's the reason all of my concepts are all mixed up. They do have a realtionship in my domain model and DCD, that's why all this mess.

Comment: The ability of admins to manage reportedcomments is system behavior, not knowledge, so it belongs in your system model, not your data model. Your data model should organize the facts required by the system, no more. Your system model should describe the behavioral components of the system. I count the DBMS as one of those components, so that I can model interaction between it and other parts of the system.

Comment: Also, I think Admin should be handled as a subtype or attribute of User, not an independent entity set. Admins should have all the same information requirements and abilities as users, and more, right?

Comment: I agree with you, I separated it here for better understanding of the example and to make it more clear that admin and user have different responsibilities.

Comment: Can you elaborate it a little more?

"Your data model should organize the facts required by the system, no more."

my system demands admin to control/manage/review reported Comments. So in yes/no answer should my data model include this functionality?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130873/discussion-between-saif-ullah-and-reaanb).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some fundamental misunderstandings about Entity-Relationship models/diagrams and relational modeling.

Entity types/tables have box icons and relationship types/tables have diamond icons. Participations of entities in relationships are the lines/FKs. Your diagram *already has* a relationship & table between reported comments and admins: `reviews`. If you want the rows satisfying a *different* application relationship/association then you either have to express it in terms of given/base relationships via a query or you have to add a new given/base relationship & table.

```
-- REPORTEDCOMMENTID identifies reporting of comment COMMENTID ...
select * from ReportedCommentInfo

--admin ADMINID has name NAME and ...
select * from Admin   

--   REPORTEDCOMMENTID identifies reporting of comment COMMENTID ...
-- AND admin ADMINID has name NAME and ...
select * from ReportedCommentInfo join Admin
```

You don't need lines/FKs to query. They're just given/base participations. (*Misrepresentations* of ER modeling call participations/FKs "relationships".)

PS There are tables and there are jobs. Tables record the state of the business. A job involves reading and/or updating some relevant tables. An ER diagram just shows the tables. You seem to be confusing ER diagrams with data flow diagrams, which are about how people use tables to do their job. An ER model (schema/diagram) for the data you have in your schema would have User, Admin & Comment entities, a Posts relation on users and comments and a Reports relationship on users and comments, which could be considered a Report associative entity. As to variations, including your schema, you need to *pick a particular design method* and follow it. Also, you haven't given justification for using the ER diagram you gave.

Comment: Basically that's my question, should there exist a relationship between the two tables?
If  no then should I change DB schema to also show that relation?

and if I should change DB schema then how can should I change it.

or it is not necessary for an ERD to show relation between each real world entities.

Comment: it means admin will be performing its duty but it's not necessary for admin to have any kind of relationship in ERD actually with reportedComments?

so admin will be lying separately on a side in ERD?

Comment: *You* have to tell *us* what relationships you want to record in your database. Assume *entities* user, admin & comment and *relationship* posts are ok. But your diagram has a ReportedCommentInfo entities... odd. (Maybe it's an *associative entity* of some relationship?) Also odd are the relationships you claim involve them. So please edit your question to explain what a reported comment info entity is (if it's not an error) and to give each relationship's *predicate*--a statement template parameterized by column/entity names--like I did..

Comment: There *is* a relationship in your diagram between admin and reported comment infos. Do you want it or not? You put it there. What do you mean, "it means admin will be doing its duty"? Please write clearly. If you mean, the diamond means something about what admins do, no, that is not what it means in an ER diagram, and this kind of diagram is not for saying that sort of thing. Did you find out what a data flow diagram is and what an ER diagram (the style with diamonds) is?